# Popping list randomly with math.random() and math.floor()

Tags: javascript, html

I want to randomize the popping of the list of the baby variable, but it's only popping the baby[1].

```
<body>

    <h1 id="1">bebe</h1>
    <h1 id="2">tae</h1>

    <script>
        var baby = [document.getElementById('1').innerText, 
        document.getElementById('2').innerText]

        bot = Math.floor(Math.random() * baby.length)

        if (bot == 0) {
            baby.pop(0)
        }

        if (bot == 1) {
            baby.pop(1)
        }

        console.log(baby)
    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: `.pop()` does not take any parameters. And it only ever remove the last item.

Answer (score 1):

that's not `[].pop()`, that's `[].splice(start, deleteCount, replacement?)`

```
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
console.log(
  a.splice(3, 1), // [4]
  a,              // [1, 2, 3, 5]
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Pop always removes the last element in the list.

You want to use `baby.splice(0, 1)` and `baby.splice(1, 1)`. The first number is the index and the second number is the number of elements you want to remove.

Answer (score 1):

`pop()` does not take any arguments, it always remove the last index.

---

You can use the `bot` variable as the [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) index:

```js
var baby = [document.getElementById('1').innerText, 
document.getElementById('2').innerText]

bot = Math.floor(Math.random() * baby.length)

baby.splice(bot, 1) 

console.log(baby)
```

```html
<h1 id="1">bebe</h1>
<h1 id="2">tae</h1>
```

---

**Note**: Be careful when using Integers as ID:

- [What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)